# JQuery position.top() slow with lots of elements

Tags: jquery

i have a need to figure out which element on a list is at the top of a page.  My solution is to use the jQuery each to loop over the elements and look at the position.

This functions fine but performance degrades when there are lots of elements. See this fiddle for a simplified example

http://jsfiddle.net/AnfZg/3/

Here is the odd things I am noticing

- it is the first call to position.top() that takes time
- I am seeing wildly different behaviours in chrome (almost 3 seconds) and firefox (less than 1 second)

Is there a better solution to what I am trying to do?

Here is the code

```
<p>Log:
<div id="log">
</div>
</p>

Items:
<ul id="items">
</ul>


for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    $("#items").append("<li id='item_" + i + "'>" + i + "</li>");
}

var top = new Date().getTime();

$("li[id^='item_']").each(function() {

  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var top = $(this).position().top;
  var end = new Date().getTime();

  var time = end - start;


  if (time > 1) {
     $("#log").append($(this).attr('id') + ": " + time + "<br/>");
  }

});

var bottom = new Date().getTime();

var overalltime = bottom - top;

$("#log").append("Overall Time: " + overalltime + "<br/>");
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the problem? Do the elements move? How do they move? etc.

Comment: In the actual app - when the user scrolls the page, I want something to happen after every 10th element reaches the top of the page.

As I mentioned the code I have works, it detects the item at the top of the page.

However if the page has thousands of elements the detection function becomes too slow and the page is unresponsive.

Comment: Why dont you use scroll function? are elements same height?

Comment: This function will be called on the scroll function.  I cannot guarantee the height of elements and there are other elements on the page so this would not be accurate enough.

basically if I can figure out why position.top() is so slow on the first call then my solution would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, a few ideas:

- You probably have no idea how much slower jQuery is when you're doing some intensive work like this, it does a bunch of extra work to make everything a bit easier to use. Try using the native JavaScript functions and you'll definitely notice a performance difference.

  ```
  // get all <li> elements
  var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // get all class="item" elements
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

  // offsetTop is the top position of the element
  items[0].offsetTop;
  ```
- If you have knowledge of how high the elements are (or approximately how high) then you can measure/estimate that value and only check the range of elements that you need to. For example, if you know there are only going to be around 50 elements in a page, just check those elements.
- You can defer most of the work for later so that the browser is only ever handling a manageable amount of work by only checking the current screens worth and a little more, this is basically the same idea as loading more as you hit the bottom of Twitter/Google+/etc.
- Make sure you're only checking every 10th element's height if that's all that matters, you can do this on a `for` loop by using `i += 10` at the end.

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 10)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

I have tried it out using javascript and looping through the results. It appears to be faster coming down from 3 seconds to just over 2.  Perhaps it will not be possible to get this almost instantaneous.

I am deferring the work, loading a certain amount of elements at a time but as the page grows that is when the problems start.

The thing that baffles me is why the first call to position.top() takes over two seconds and all the rest <= 1 ms.  Does that first call do the loading of the dom?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with that yea, the page warming up.